# Cannot append file to Formdata using multer

Tags: node.js, file, multipartform-data, multer, form-data

I am creating a blog so, created a form that takes the title and description of the post and also the user can upload the file. I am creating this app in mern stack. This is in the client-side from where the user can enter the information. I could not understand how to send both text as well as file. I even tried `upload.any()` in post request.

```
const Addpost=()=> {
const [title, settitle] = useState('')
const [des, setdes] = useState('')
const [file, setfile] = useState('')
const {addPost}=useContext(Globalcontext)

const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
e.preventDefault()
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', file)
console.log([...formData])

const addedValue={
    title,
    des,
   formData
}
addPost(addedValue)
settitle('')
setdes('')
setfile('')
}
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name="title" value={title} onChange={(e)=>settitle(e.target.value)}/>
                <input type="text" name="des" value={des} onChange={(e)=>setdes(e.target.value)}/>
                <input type="file" name="file" onChange={(e)=>{setfile(e.target.files)}} />
                <button type='submit' value='submit'>Add Post</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Addpost
```

When I tried to console out the value in formData using `console.log([...formData])` I got `[object FileList]` as the value of the file. But the state file has the information about the file stored as an array which could not be appended to the formData. I tried to append the title and des to the formData and was successful. The problem was only with the file or images append. I have passed the Content-type in the header but could not get what went wrong.